# Control WP7 and WP8 app with bluetooth headset

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, bluetooth, windows-phone-8

I have developed a music player app for Windows Phone 7.5 and Windows Phone 8. Now I want to listen to the music with various bluetooth devices. I can connect it to my phone and listen to music, so that's working just fine. But it acts weird in certain scenarios. If the music is paused it will resume on the speakers if I disconnect the bluetooth. I can see in my log that it receives a user action to `UserAction.SEEK` to the position it was when I turned off bluetooth. At this point, the `player.Position` variable has somehow gotten to be 0, so it goes to 0 and back to where I was. And I don't do anything that would cause that action.

What I am asking: Is there a way to take over control or to get any control in the `AudioPlaybackAgent` that I use of what happens when I do something with my bluetooth devices. Is there any event that occurs, or is all this handled by the OS? If so, why does my application behave differently than the stock app? Also, why am I receiving a `UserAction.SEEK` when I turn of my bluetooth device?

If my question is unclear, please don`t hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with the platform, but is fixed in WP8 GDR2. You can workaround the issue by detecting an *OnUserAction* sequence of `Pause` `Seek` `Play`. Once detected, you can pause on the next call to *OnPlayerStateChanged*. A few things to be aware of:

- Consecutive calls to *OnUserAction* aren't guaranteed to be called on the same instance of *AudioPlayer*, so any state should be stored in static state.
- The track will play from the speaker for a brief moment, so you might want to set the volume to 0 (after making note of it's previous value, of course)

I've posted a [Gist to GitHub with a full implementation](https://gist.github.com/richardszalay/6260553). Example usage and a more detailed rundown of the problem is [available on my blog](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2013/08/18/working-around-the-windows-phone-bluetooth-disconnection-issue/).